# how does vim change the width of its terminal emulator?

Tags: vim, terminal, ansi-escape

When Vim is given a command like `:set columns=88`, it changes the width of the terminal window it is running in. How does it do this?

I've always assumed there are ANSI codes to change the terminal window width and height, but have repeatedly failed to figure out what they are.

Comment: The good people at https://vi.stackexchange.com might know this.

Comment: Vim is open source, read its code.

Comment: I'm a little intimidated by the size and famed complexity of the codebase.

Answer (score 1):

For xterm-specific codes see http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h2-Functions-using-CSI-_-ordered-by-the-final-character_s_:

```
CSI Ps ; Ps ; Ps t
    Window manipulation
    …
    Ps = 8  ;  height ;  width -> Resize the text area to given
    height and width in characters.
```